# Is it possible to upgrade Registry smart contract?

Tags: proxy, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am using https://yos.io/2018/10/28/upgrading-solidity-smart-contracts/ link for upgrading smart contracts which have listed Smart Contract Upgrade Mechanisms.

Is it possible to make change itself in registry smart contract and upgrade it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a registry contract is to store a mutable reference to the latest versions of your smart contract modules. It serves as a first point of access for your decentralized application.

So there are two options if you want to upgrade a registry contract:

- have another (fixed) registry contract pointing to your (dynamic) registry contract
- update the reference to your registry contract in all places that use it (i.e. the frontend application)

I hope this answers your question.